# why my index.tsx can not found Clock Module?

Tags: typescript, webpack

Here is my import code in the **index.tsx** file.

```
import Clock from "./utility/clock";
```

and here is my tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "sourceMap": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "allowJs": true,
  },
  "include": [
      "./src"
  ]
}
```

Before ask this question, I have check this page: [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

I am sure, my Clock component file path is right, as follow picture.

[image]

I am very confused why the Clock module could not be found. Thanks for your help.

======Update webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
let isDev = false;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
isDev = env === "development" ? true : false;
console.log(isDev ? "开发环境" : "生产环境");
const htmlsMap = [
  {
    template: "index",
    chunks: ["index"]
  },
  {
    template: "d3",
    chunks: ["d3"]
  }
];

const htmlFiles = (function() {
  let result = [];
  htmlsMap.map((item) => {
    result.push(
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: `./src/template/${item.template}.html`,
        chunks: item.chunks,
        filename: `${item.template}.html`
      })
    );
  });
  return result;
}());

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // commons: ["jquery", "bootstrap"], 
    index: ["./src/template/index.js"],
    d3: ["./src/template/d3.js"]
  },
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("build"),
    publicPath: isDev ? "/build/" : "./",
    filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: "html-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.(eot|woff|ttf|eot|woff2)$/, loader: "file-loader"
    },{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: "imports-loader?define=>false"
    }, { 
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" 
    }, {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ["babel-loader"]
    }, {
      test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
      loader: "file-loader?name=img-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]"
    },{
      test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/, loader: "imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window"
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: __dirname,
      manifest: require("./manifest.json"),
    }),
  ].concat( htmlFiles)
    .concat(
      isDev ?
        // 开发环境
        [
          new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
          new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
          // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        ]
        :
        // 生产环境
        [
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
              warnings: false
            }
          }),
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
              NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
            }
          })
        ]
    )
};
```

=====update 2: clock.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Clock extends Component<any, any>{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        I plan to design a clock by CSS
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default Clock;
```

Comment: can you give your `webpack.config.js` as well?

Comment: @MartinShishkov I have posted it.

Comment: do you have a default export in `clock.tsx`?

Comment: @ChristianSantos definitely, I posted **clock.tsx**  too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are missing a `resolve.extensions` section in your webpack config. Try with this:

```
import Clock from "./utility/clock.tsx";
```

or adding this to your webpack config

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [/*your other extensions here*/, ".tsx"]
}
```

That way you can exclude the file extension when importing. Also, be careful to add the `resolve` section at the proper level in `module.exports`

Comment: Actually, if add **.tsx** on path string, [at-loader] will push some error as follow: [at-loader] ./src/component/index.tsx:9:19 
    TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing './utility/clock' instead.

Comment: then you should try with `resolve`. What version of webpack is this anyway?

Comment: "webpack": "^3.5.6" is the webpack version. And when I add **resolve** almost all file can not be found, strange thing.  (O_0)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused it two more days! I use your advise to solute this issue: **resolve.extension**. Actually, I can't figure it out the reason. Thanks too much again.

Comment: In addition,  type check can not allow **.tsx** in tsx file.